# A Value That Should Be The Same But It Changes

Tags: c, glib

This part of could should return always the same hash value to each Key isn't it ?
But I find that values related to keys they change to each update ...

How can I fix the same value of each key whenever there is an update?

```
u_int64_t* ReturnValue=NULL;
u_int32_t a;
int sz;

a = nothl(as->addr32[0]);
sz = update(size);

if (ReturnValue=(u_int64_t*)g_hash_table_lookup(hashtable, (gpointer)&a))
{
g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)&a, (gpointer)ReturnValue);
// I didnt't use g_hash_table_replace() because it will free the key then the value change
}

else g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)&a, (gpointer)&sz)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to insert using a reference to `sz`, assuming this is a function call. You should `malloc` this instead so that the value doesn't get lost after the function call returns (and then you're pointing to a random memory location that used to be your function's stack).  Just make sure you include the code to free this memory, too.

Comment: @B Mitch : please have a look in my following answer

Comment: @B Mitch

Yes"you're pointing to a random memory location" was the right answer!! Thanks !!! Now I have another question: I want to update the Volume to each @IP. So that for example after each 5 s I add V(i) of each @IP(i). Ok Now it works fine but my problem is that after a certain period I find that sometimes the same ip adress is repeated twice or even a lot of times so that in the output I find the same @IP repeated too many times. It is like there is a problem with the hash table or something like that. Here is the code :

Comment: `int update_hashTable( ... ) `

`{`
`...`


`u_int32_t *a; a = (u_int32_t*)malloc(sizeof(u_int32_t));`


`a = ntohl(as->addr32[0]);`


`sz = update(size);`


`if (ReturnValue=(u_int32_t)g_hash_table_lookup(hashtable, a)) {`


`ReturnValue +=sz;`


`g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)a, gpointer)ReturnValue); `

`}\n`

`else g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)a, (gpointer)sz) }`

Comment: `int update_hashTable( ... ) 

{
...
u_int32_t *a; a = (u_int32_t*)malloc(sizeof(u_int32_t));


a = ntohl(as->addr32[0]);


sz = update(size);


if (ReturnValue=(u_int32_t)g_hash_table_lookup(hashtable, a)) {


ReturnValue +=sz;


g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)a, gpointer)ReturnValue); 
}
else g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)a, (gpointer)sz) }`

Comment: You're overwriting the malloc'd pointer to `a` in the `ntohl`.    That should be `*a = ntohl(...)`.  Not sure about the repeating values. If they continue, I'd open a new question.

Comment: @B Mitch here is the real question in fact hope you can have an idea and thakns!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178857/behaviour-of-an-hashtable-using-glib