# Behaviour of an hashtable using glib

Tags: c, linux, hash, hashtable, glib

I want to update the Volume to each @IP. So that for example after each 5 s I add V(i) of each @IP(i). Ok Now **the hash table works fine it keeps updated after every T seconds**. But the problem is that **after a certain period** I find that sometimes the same ip adress is repeated twice or even a lot of times **within the hash table**. So that when I close the process I find the same @IP repeated too many times. It is like there is a problem with the hash table or something like that.

Here is the code **this funcion "update_hashTable()" is so important it is called every X seconds** I suspect in fact a memory leak ... because I always call `malloc` for IP@.
but it keeps working ... any idea ???

```
int update_hashTable( ... ) {

u_int32_t *a;

... //declarations

struct pf_addr *as;


as = ks->addr[0];

a = (u_int32_t*)malloc(sizeof(u_int32_t));

*a = ntohl(as->addr32[0]);

sz = value; // no matter it is... an int for example

if (ReturnValue=(u_int32_t)g_hash_table_lookup(hashtable, a)) {

  ReturnValue +=sz;
  g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)a, gpointer)ReturnValue);
}
else {
  g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, (gpointer)a, (gpointer)sz);
}
```

Comment: English has other punctuation symbols besides `.`

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you appear to have a memory leak, but this isn't your problem. The problem is that the true-path of your if statement simply reinserts a second value associated with the same key, which is not what you want.

The typical pattern for this check-if-exists and increment algorithm is usually something like

```
gpointer val = g_hash_table_lookup(hash_table, key);
if (val == NULL) {
    val = g_malloc0(...);
    g_hash_table_insert(hash_table, key, val);
}
*val = /* something */;
```

The important thing to take away from this is that once you have a pointer to the value associated with some key, you can simply modify it directly.

If this code will be executed by multiple threads in parallel, then the entire block should be protected by a mutex, perhaps with GMutex: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Threads.html

gcc provides atomic builtin intrinsics, say for atomically incrementing the value, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Comment: *once you have a pointer to the value associated with some key, you can simply modify it directly.* This will really help me thanks. But I have 2 remarks on what you wrote:
1)
val = g_malloc0(...);
g_hash_table_insert(hash_table, key, val);
seems that val is not initiated with 0 although you used g_malloc0 ... When I execute the program it gives some random variable.
2)
about ` *val ` it didn't work because it points in fact on a void. I used instead : `* (u_int32_t*)val) += sz`  (sz is an u_int32_t) but things don't go really as you said:*once you have a pointer to the value associate ...*

Comment: Yes, of course you'll have to cast *val to assign its value. It was assumed that you'd be able to manage this part without explicitly stating it, since the question was about glib and not C. Anyway, I seem to have answered the question asked, so please accept my answer.